# How to have multiple layouts in one activity in android?

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview, android-custom-view, viewgroup

What i want in my activity is two buttons on the top in one single line.. and below that i want a framelayout in which i want an imageview and i wil add my custom view on the top of imageview. I tried a lot but i am having a lot of confusion.

[image]

Shown in the image below is somewhat like i want. 
I want to use framelayout because i want to add my custom view over my imageview. But if i add button on framelayout it comes above the image. It is getting really confusing and messy for me.

Comment: could u please paste your code?

Answer (score 0):

I did'nt know that we could nest two layouts in a single activity. I nested LinearLayout with FrameLayout and my problem got solved.. Cheers!